# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, i can't push comments to data array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can't push comments to the data array. the comments have been created (they have been added to comment collection). How can I push them to data array? Here are some screenshots of my code: [Comments Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4tAS.png) and
,[The comments array is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwAO5.png),
[Camp Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ1a7.png)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var camp = require("./models/camp");
var Comment = require("./models/comment");

var data = [
    {
        name: "Cloud's Rest", 
        image: // a link goes here
    },
    {
        name: "Desert Mesa", 
        image: //
    },
    {
        name: "Canyon Floor", 
        image: //
    }
];

function seedDB(){
   //Remove all campgrounds that existed in the database & create new campgrounds with data array.

   camp.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("removed campgrounds!");
         //add a few campgrounds
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            camp.create(seed, function(err, camp){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("added a campground");
                    //create a comment
                    Comment.create(
                        {
                            text: "This place is great, but I wish there was internet",
                            author: "Homer"
                        }, function(err, comment){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                camp.comments.push(comment);
                                camp.save();
                                console.log("Created new comment");
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    //add a few comments
}


module.exports = seedDB;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you intend on posting code here, you might consider removing the syntax errors first. We all realize that node components won't load and such, but  the error has to do with a `}`. Now, it appears you are passing in `campground` for your variable rather than `camp` at that place in your code.

Comment: yeah, so, camp.comments is undefined. You've provided nothing that would indicate that it should be defined... so... working as intended?

Comment: Hi @KevinB, no I don't think so. please check my schemas above.

Comment: @AnasAl-Sharif No, the error doesn't lie. It is undefined.

Comment: @KevinB I know that the error doesn't lie, that's why i asked the question in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This answer presumes the syntax error is due to a missing `});` after the `camp.remove()` function.

Without knowing what `Camp` looks like, I will presume that `camp.create()` will pass the definition of a `camp` to the callback method. If that is the case, then it would appear you need to use `campground` rather than `camp` since it would appear that the new `camp` is passed into that callback function as `campground`.

Comment: Hi Randy. I'am sorry there was a typo in my code above and I fixed it. i also added a picture of my camp schema. Thank you.

Comment: But did you change your references from `camp` to `campground` in your code? If so, what was the result?

Comment: Hi Randy, yes I changed it and it works fine now, thanks a lot for your help. Have a great day.